# JTable adjusting column width or height

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

In my JTable is there a way to restrict the user in adjusting the height of the row or width of a column using the mouse.I am already using

```
JTable table=new JTable();
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

The table is inside a scroll panel.

Comment: Do you want to allow column/row adjusting, but limit it, or simply dis-allow column/row adjustment altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);